# ...Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level”

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

here is my code....i dont whats wrong with my code....error of identification line 161...
exatly error like this....line 161....Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level”

help
help
help

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import Adafruit_DHT
import urllib2
import smbus
import time
from ctypes import c_short

#Register Address
regCall   = 0xAA
regMean   = 0xF4
regMSB    = 0xF6
regLSB    = 0xF7
regPres   = 0x34
regTemp   = 0x2e

DEBUG = 1
sample = 2
deviceAdd =0x77

humi=""
temp=""

#bus = smbus.SMBus(0)  #for Pi1 uses 0
I2cbus = smbus.SMBus(1) # for Pi2 uses 1

DHTpin = 17

key="30BCDSRQ52AOI3UA"       # Enter your Write API key from ThingSpeak

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# Define GPIO to LCD mapping
LCD_RS = 18
LCD_EN  = 23
LCD_D4 = 24
LCD_D5 = 16
LCD_D6 = 20
LCD_D7 = 21

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)     
GPIO.setup(LCD_E, GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.setup(LCD_RS, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(LCD_D4, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(LCD_D5, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(LCD_D6, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(LCD_D7, GPIO.OUT) 

def convert1(data, i):   # signed 16-bit value
  return c_short((data[i]<< 8) + data[i + 1]).value

def convert2(data, i):   # unsigned 16-bit value
  return (data[i]<< 8) + data[i+1] 

def readBmp180(addr=deviceAdd):    
  value = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, regCall, 22)  # Read calibration data

  # Convert byte data to word values
  AC1 = convert1(value, 0)
  AC2 = convert1(value, 2)
  AC3 = convert1(value, 4)
  AC4 = convert2(value, 6)
  AC5 = convert2(value, 8)
  AC6 = convert2(value, 10)
  B1  = convert1(value, 12)
  B2  = convert1(value, 14)
  MB  = convert1(value, 16)
  MC  = convert1(value, 18)
  MD  = convert1(value, 20)

    # Read temperature
  bus.write_byte_data(addr, regMean, regTemp)
  time.sleep(0.005)
  (msb, lsb) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, regMSB, 2)
  P2 = (msb << 8) + lsb

  # Read pressure
  bus.write_byte_data(addr, regMean, regPres + (sample << 6))
  time.sleep(0.05)
  (msb, lsb, xsb) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, regMSB, 3)
  P1 = ((msb << 16) + (lsb << 8) + xsb) >> (8 - sample)

   # Refine temperature
  X1 = ((P2 - AC6) * AC5) >> 15
  X2 = (MC << 11) / (X1 + MD)
  B5 = X1 + X2
  temperature = (B5 + 8) >> 4

  # Refine pressure
  B6  = B5 - 4000
  B62 = B6 * B6 >> 12
  X1  = (B2 * B62) >> 11
  X2  = AC2 * B6 >> 11
  X3  = X1 + X2
  B3  = (((AC1 * 4 + X3) << sample) + 2) >> 2

  X1 = AC3 * B6 >> 13
  X2 = (B1 * B62) >> 16
  X3 = ((X1 + X2) + 2) >> 2
  B4 = (AC4 * (X3 + 32768)) >> 15
  B7 = (P1 - B3) * (50000 >> sample)

  P = (B7 * 2) / B4

  X1 = (P >> 8) * (P >> 8)
  X1 = (X1 * 3038) >> 16
  X2 = (-7357 * P) >> 16
  pressure = P + ((X1 + X2 + 3791) >> 4)

  return (str(pressure/100.0))

def readDHT():
    humi, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT11, DHTpin)
    return (str(int(humi)), str(int(temp)))

def lcd_init():
  lcdcmd(0x33) 
  lcdcmd(0x32) 
  lcdcmd(0x06)
  lcdcmd(0x0C) 
  lcdcmd(0x28) 
  lcdcmd(0x01) 
  time.sleep(0.0005)

def lcdcmd(ch): 
  GPIO.output(RS, 0)
  GPIO.output(D4, 0)
  GPIO.output(D5, 0)
  GPIO.output(D6, 0)
  GPIO.output(D7, 0)
  if ch&0x10==0x10:
    GPIO.output(D4, 1)
  if ch&0x20==0x20:
    GPIO.output(D5, 1)
  if ch&0x40==0x40:
    GPIO.output(D6, 1)
  if ch&0x80==0x80:
    GPIO.output(D7, 1)
  GPIO.output(EN, 1)
  time.sleep(0.0005)
  GPIO.output(EN, 0)

  # Low bits
  GPIO.output(D4, 0)
  GPIO.output(D5, 0)
  GPIO.output(D6, 0)
  GPIO.output(D7, 0)
  if ch&0x01==0x01:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, 1)
  if ch&0x02==0x02:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, 1)
  if ch&0x04==0x04:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, 1)
  if ch&0x08==0x08:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, 1)
  GPIO.output(EN, 1)
  time.sleep(0.0005)
  GPIO.output(EN, 0)

 def lcddata(ch): 
  GPIO.output(RS, 1)
  GPIO.output(D4, 0)
  GPIO.output(D5, 0)
  GPIO.output(D6, 0)
  GPIO.output(D7, 0)
  if ch&0x10==0x10:
    GPIO.output(D4, 1)
  if ch&0x20==0x20:
    GPIO.output(D5, 1)
  if ch&0x40==0x40:
    GPIO.output(D6, 1)
  if ch&0x80==0x80:
    GPIO.output(D7, 1)
  GPIO.output(EN, 1)
  time.sleep(0.0005)
  GPIO.output(EN, 0)

  # Low bits
  GPIO.output(D4, 0)
  GPIO.output(D5, 0)
  GPIO.output(D6, 0)
  GPIO.output(D7, 0)
  if ch&0x01==0x01:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D4, 1)
  if ch&0x02==0x02:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D5, 1)
  if ch&0x04==0x04:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D6, 1)
  if ch&0x08==0x08:
    GPIO.output(LCD_D7, 1)
  GPIO.output(EN, 1)
  time.sleep(0.0005)
  GPIO.output(EN, 0)

def lcdstring(Str):
  l=0;
  l=len(Str)
  for i in range(l):
    lcddata(ord(message[i]))

lcd_init()
 lcdcmd(0x01)
lcdstring("Circuit Digest")
lcdcmd(0xc0)
lcdstring("Welcomes you")
time.sleep(3) # 3 second delay

# main() function
def main():

    print 'System Ready...'
    URL = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=%s' % key
    print "Wait...."
    while True:
            (humi, temp)= readDHT()
            (pressure) =readBmp180()

            lcdcmd(0x01)
            lcdstring("Humi#Temp#P(hPa)")
            lcdstring(humi+'%'+"  %sC  %s" %(temp, pressure))
            finalURL = URL +"&field1=%s&field2=%s"%(humi, temp)+"&field3=%s" %(pressure) 
            print finalURL
            s=urllib2.urlopen(finalURL);
            print  humi+ " " + temp + " " + pressure
            s.close()
            time.sleep(10)



if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: `lcd_init()
 lcdcmd(0x01)
lcdstring("Circuit Digest")`. next time isolate the lines instead of posting your whole code. You won't even have to post here.

Comment: You have two different indent level...one with 2 spaces and one with tabs. And there's a extra space in front `lcdcmd(0x01)` and what Jean said

Comment: as you might have noticed - Python is white-space / indentation-sensitive. remove the extra space and pretend you never posted this to Stack Overflow

Comment: I recommend you read the Stackoverflow page "How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So I copy and pasted your code and there is an extra space in front of line 161

```
def lcddata(ch):
```

and line 203

```
lcdcmd(0x01)
```

and all this code has extra tabs in it it shouldn't

```
def main():

print 'System Ready...'
URL = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=%s' % key
print "Wait...."
while True:
        (humi, temp)= readDHT()
        (pressure) =readBmp180()

        lcdcmd(0x01)
        lcdstring("Humi#Temp#P(hPa)")
        lcdstring(humi+'%'+"  %sC  %s" %(temp, pressure))
        finalURL = URL +"&field1=%s&field2=%s"%(humi, temp)+"&field3=%s" %(pressure) 
        print finalURL
        s=urllib2.urlopen(finalURL);
        print  humi+ " " + temp + " " + pressure
        s.close()
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Welcome Matthew! Thank you for willing to help, but the usage here is not to write answers to such questions who were only caused by simple typos (especially when someone already noted that in the comments!) Furthermore, the question is one month old, so there's little chance that your work will help the OP. But keep on the good work!